# ReactJS How can I edit user with functional component useSelector

Tags: reactjs, django, state

With the code I have, I am getting the user in input but the input won't change when I type

here is the input

```
<div className="pInput">
  <label>last Name</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    className="ppInput"
    value={user.last_name} 
    onChange={(e) => HandleEditDesc(e)} 
    placeholder={user.last_name}
  />
</div>
```

Here is my on change function

```
  e.preventDefault()
  user.last_name = useSelector((state) => e.target.value);
  state.auth.user.last_name = user.last_name
}
```

Here is how I am getting the user

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Axios from "axios";

const Profile = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user);
  const subscriptionStatus = useSelector(
    (state) => state.auth.subscriptionStatus
  );
```

I am using Django as my backend

Comment: Why are you using `useSelector` to get `e.target.value`?

Comment: I don't know how to do it I mostly do class components

Comment: On the top of the on change function is function HandleEditDesc(e) {

Comment: useSelector is to read the value from the store . What you need is an action to dispatch to the store which will update the lastName in the user . https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch . react-redux has one of the best documentation. I would highly recommend to have a look at it .

Comment: I right now  will thanks

Comment: The first step would be to remove `useSelector` from that line, since Redux state has nothing to do with the input value.  Beyond that, you'll also need to update state properly.  Just setting a value on the returned state object ("user" in this case) won't do anything.  It'll update that value locally, but as soon as the component re-renders that value will be lost.  Never directly mutate state objects.  Instead, use Redux to update the state with the new value.  This will automatically trigger your components to re-render as needed.